# .docx to .txt in lazarus

Tags: text, pascal, docx, lazarus

I need to write a program which gets text from docx and doc files and put it to txt file. 
So, the problem is that I don't know how to get text from microsoft word document in lazarus. So, if you know how to do it, please, write or send a link me where I can see the code which get text from word. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Word can be used over COM. See [Office automation in Lazarus](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Office_Automation#Office_on_Windows). Most Delphi examples will also apply.